# Getting random 500 error with Apache2 + mod_wsgi + django 'Remote end closed connection without response'

Tags: django, apache2, python-3.5, mod-wsgi

I have my django working correctly under apache2, but sometimes I get this message:

> ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed
>   connection without response',))

Reloading solves the problem, but this is not a solution for a production server.

I tried Updating Django and mod_wsgi

I get the following stack trace:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdSG8KB79POkaJ6Eu3N8Oh1y6CNEfFSk/view?usp=sharing

Somebody with the same issue?

Comment: edits for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is coming from the requests library that is called from /var/frontend/frontendApp/api/users.py:93. I ques it's your backend for authenticating the user, look in the backend app logs why it closes the connection (maybe to many request to backend app?)

Comment: It is, api was outdated and we were getting a lot of 301 from responses, we are going to perform some stress tests now, but looks fine, thanks a lot!